# OFFSET EDGE Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

Is there any reason why I cant find edge offset in my blender 2.9? On tutorial I watched form Blender 2.8 there offset tool but I cant seem to find it.

Btw. Is there another way to offset edge?[image]

Comment: Probably because it's a third party addon. There's a video of it being used in 2.9 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vu0MRcq61I). Hope you can understand the thick Scottish accent! :^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this add-on to do "offset edges"
https://gist.github.com/Bombaba/7e5d1343678542d44215346768c7d839

[image]

also there are 3 offset's mode
its very useful!